# HTML: Submit form on radio button check

Tags: html

I have a form that displays two radio buttons (using PHP).

```
echo "<form action=\"next.php\" method=\"post\">";
   echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"paid\" value=\"0\" checked=\"checked\">No<br>";
   echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"paid\" value=\"1\">Yes<br>";
echo "</form>";
```

One of the radio buttons is always checked by default.
If the user checks the other radio button, I would like the form to submit itself (without the user having to click a submit button).

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery (put the code inside the `</body>` tag):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('input[name=paid]').change(function(){
        $('form').submit();
   });
  });

</script>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/ryBs6/)**

To add jQuery to your page, put this line inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
```

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but I have no experience in javascript and will likely not need it on my site except for this bit. Is that a javascript function that I need to put in my page's head? I understand the code though, just don't know where it goes.

Comment: Yes i will add explanation

Answer (score 37):

The *simplest* (but considered bad practice) would be appending inline `onchange="this.form.submit();"` attribute to your input elements like:

```php
echo '<form action="next.php" method="post">
  <label><input onchange="this.form.submit();" type="radio" name="paid" value="0" checked="checked">No</label><br>
  <label><input onchange="this.form.submit();" type="radio" name="paid" value="1">Yes</label>
</form>';
```

but inline *`on*`* attributes like *`onchange`* make code hard to debug and maintain. JavaScript should be in one place only and that's the respective script tag or file. Therefore here's this *better* suggestion:

```php
echo '<form action="next.php" method="post">
 <label><input type="radio" name="paid" value="0" checked="checked">No</label><br>
 <label><input type="radio" name="paid" value="1">Yes</label>
</form>';
```

```js
const elForm = document.querySelector("form[action='next.php']");
const elsRadio = elForm.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");

elsRadio.forEach((elInp) => {
  elInp.addEventListener("change", () => {
    elForm.submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: you're answer was much more simpler. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use an onchange listener:

```
$("#paid").change(function(){
alert("test");
});
```

You'll just have to give your radio button an id to go along with the name. The ID can be the same as the name, to keep it simple for you.